# jqGrid show editable dropdown list while adding/updating record

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid for showing list of customers. Using same grid user will be able to add new record or update existing. There is one requirement i.e. while adding/updating record one of columns should be editable dropdown which will show predefined options OR user can type new option if she doesn't like existing options. I could find many solutions with non editable dropdown however ran out luck with editable dropdown. If someone has any pointers on this then that will be great help.

Comment: Why not just do an autocomplete? It will be much easier to do that with relaxed set of rules where users can easily type new option. There are lots of examples of autocomplete in jqgrid on here.

Comment: We thought of that option however user must know list of available options upfront to pickup desired existing option and that's not so good user experience.

Comment: You can set autocomplete on focus which will list out all the available options in the autocomplete as soon as the textbox is in focus. Something like this `.on('focus', function(event) {
                var self = this;
                $(self).autocomplete( "search", "");
            });` should work.

Comment: Thanks. Looks fair workaround. Will try it out if editable dropdown is not possible.